# Symfony - Restrict access to a route for users with a particular role

Tags: php, symfony

In security.yml I have routes secured for users by defining the minimum role the user must have. E.g.

- { path: ^/a/clients,              role: MY_CUSTOM_ROLE }

Is there a way to negate this access to that the only people allowed through are those that do NOT have this role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can easily do that with symfony expression language(new feature in 2.4 I think).
Some example:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/_internal/secure, allow_if: "'127.0.0.1' == request.getClientIp() or has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" }
```

For more details go to:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/8913

For version 2.3.4(the current stable one), you need to manually create another custom role that is the negation of MY_CUSTOM_ROLE.

Comment: It is not possible to use !has_role('ROLE_BANNED') for example, is there a way to make it so it denies the path to a user that has the ROLE_BANNED role ?